# Mostrar alert de bootstrap despues de un elemento

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo el siguiente `div`que contiene un `input` con su respectivo `id`:

```
<div class="form-group linea numBoxCaja 1">
  <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="caja1" name="caja1" 
        value="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Quiero mostrar una alerta de bootstrap despues del `input`cuando ocurre determinada acción, lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
$(".input-group #" + idCajaIden).after('<div class="alert alert-warning">strong>ADVERTENCIA!</strong> Filtro/Bolsa ya existe!.</div>');
```

Pero cuando la muestro queda de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo mostrar la alerta de la caja correctamente sin que me quede asi feo e incrustado?

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el código es correcto pero se lo debes asignar al padre (.input-group) y no al propio input

```
$(".input-group #" + idCajaIden).parent().after('<div class="alert alert-warning">strong>ADVERTENCIA!</strong> Filtro/Bolsa ya existe!.</div>');
```

agrega el parent()

saludos